# what is the time complexity of the three sum algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

it is a function to find three numbers in array whoose sum is equal to zero.

```
//helper function
bool isPresent(int*arr, int size, int index, int num)
{
    for (int i = index; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == num)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool threesum(int*arr,int size)
{
    int i = 0, j = 1;
    int sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
    while (i < size-2)
    {
        if (isPresent(arr, size, j + 1, -sum) == true)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << " + " << arr[j] << " + " << -sum << '\n';
            return true;
        }
        if (j == size)
        {
            i++;
            j = i + 1;
        }
        j++;
        sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
    }
    return false;
}
```

there are two loops in the threeSum function one is while up to size of array
second one is isPresent whose time complexity is O(n) so the time complexity of threesum function should be O(n^2) but while loop iterates more time because of j, So is  the time complexity of threesum function is O(n^2) or O(n^3)?

Comment: This is not answering the question, thus a comment: Note that this can actually be done in O(n^2) average case or O(n^2logn) worst case - by first adding all elements to a set, and then going over all pairs (your `i`,`j`) and instead of going over the array from scratch for each - just check efficiently in this set instead. (Special attention so you don't use the same element twice, it can be done by simply checking if the element found is one of the elements in the pair).

Answer (score 4):

It's O(n^3). Think how i is changing with j. Suppose, n = 10. At first i = 0, j = 1. i won't become 1, until j = 10, and then after these steps, again i = 1, j = 2. It's like writing two for loops like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
```

Comment: His solution to 3SUM is O(N³), but 3SUM in general can be as low as O(N²).

Comment: yeah, I've solved it myself using hash table. I explained his code's complexity

Answer (score 1):

The naïve approach is O(N³).

To see which sums of three are 0 all sums are computed and there are N * (N-1) * (N-2) / 4  different sums.

But you can easily improve on that bound by first indexing the numbers and then computing all the  sums of pairs, storing them in a hash table and then lookup if the negative of the sums exists and test if its components have not already been used in computing the sum. This gives O(N²).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

```
bool threesum(const vector<int>& numbers){
  std::unordered_map<int,size_t> index;
  for (size_t i=0;i!=numbers.size();++i) {
    index.insert({numbers[i],i});
  }
  for (size_t i=0;i!=numbers.size();++i) {
    for (size_t j=i+1;j!=numbers.size();++j) {
      const int n = -(numbers[i]+numbers[j]); 
      if (index.count(n)) {
        if (index[n]==i) continue;
        if (index[n]==j) continue;
        return true; 
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```